# fastlane xcode9 cocoapods dependencies fail

Tags: cocoapods, xcode9, fastlane

Xcode upgrade from 8 to 9 resulted in fastlane failing to build dependencies

I can successfully build the project on build machine using Xcode and pod install succeeds when ran from fastlane using cocoapods command.

Its the gym command thats failing there is number of other steps in the lane prior to this command but those are successfull

+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|                               Summary for gym 2.68.2                                |
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| scheme                 | XXXXXX                                                  |
| configuration          | Release                                                    |
| codesigning_identity   | iPhone Distribution: XXXX, Inc. (XXXXXX)          |
| export_method          | app-store                                                  |
| workspace              | ./XXXXX.xcworkspace                                    |
| destination            | generic/platform=iOS                                       |
| output_name            | XXXXX                                                  |
| build_path             | /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-12-08 |
| clean                  | false                                                      |
| output_directory       | .                                                          |
| silent                 | false                                                      |
| skip_package_ipa       | false                                                      |
| buildlog_path          | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                         |
| skip_profile_detection | false                                                      |
| xcode_path             | /Applications/Xcode.app                                    |
+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+

```
 set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace .........................

[16:18:22]: ▸ Building Pods/Alamofire [Release]
[16:18:22]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[16:18:22]: ▸ Building Pods/SVProgressHUD [Release]
[16:18:22]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[16:18:22]: ▸ Building Pods/Starscream [Release]
[16:18:22]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[16:18:22]: ▸ Building Pods/SwiftyJSON [Release]
[16:18:22]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[16:18:22]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[16:18:22]: ▸ The following build commands failed:
[16:18:22]: ▸ Check dependencies
[16:18:22]: ▸ Check dependencies
[16:18:22]: ▸ Check dependencies
[16:18:22]: ▸ Check dependencies
[16:18:22]: ▸ (4 failures)
▸ Building Pods/Alamofire [Release]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Building Pods/SVProgressHUD [Release]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Building Pods/Starscream [Release]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Building Pods/SwiftyJSON [Release]
▸ Check Dependencies
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

Comment: What is the rest of the error message? What command are you actually running?

Comment: gym command exit code 65 added more details to question as well

Comment: Any update on this issue? How did you solve it?